# \normalsize inside \author in class amsart

Tags: fontsize, amsart, author

When I try to compile this MWE in Overleaf (although I should rather say "minimal non-working example"):

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\title{Title}
\author{\normalsize John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

[image]

However, the code compiles correctly as expected if instead we substitute `\normalsize` by `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` or `\HUGE`. So what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clearly bad style to put any formatting in \author as the whole point is to have the author name as text with the style specfied elsewhere in the `\maketitle` setup, so while probably the macros could be made to avoid this error, removing \normalsize is the correct fix.

That said, you can use `\protect` to avoid the error.

You get a slightly different error in the current release:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\__bool_quark_recursion_tail:w ...n_tail #2?#3?!->
                                                  #1#2
l.8 \maketitle
              
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

but with `\protect` you get no error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\title{Title}
\author{\protect\normalsize John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd actually prefer to see the other sizes trigger errors in this context.  But then a better error message would be appreciated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton bug in amsart that it doesn't make `\normalsize` robust  (even if I'm not supposed to blame you these days)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `\normalsize` inside `\author`, because this would affect also the headers in the even numbered pages.

Better to patch `\@setauthors` which is responsible for typesetting the authors' names.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think to avoid the size changing in the other pages one can use she short title parameter for the `\author` command of `amsart`. As in `\author[short title]{long title}`.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo I still think that patching is better. And not necessary, in my opinion: the author name is less important than the title.